# Android studio "unfortunately [project name] stopped working", any clues of how to fix

Tags: java, xml, android-layout, android-studio, compiler-errors

Okay so I'm trying to get my app to switch to second activity on first buttonclick and return back to first activity on the second button click in the 2nd activity. At the moment I'm running into "unfortunately [project name] stopped working" and I'm not sure why this is the case, I'll be showing the code for you to try assisting me with this. Sorry about the layout of the code, I am new to this :D
Many thanks for your time!

### SearchScreenActivity.Java

```
package uk.ac.city.acnh478.courseworkproject;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class SearchScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_screen);
}

final Button clickMe2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
public void button2OnClick(View y) {
clickMe2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View y) {
Intent myIntent2 = new Intent(SearchScreenActivity.this, activityresultsscreenActivity.class);
startActivity(myIntent2);
}
});}}
```

### activityresultsscreenActivty.java;

```
package uk.ac.city.acnh478.courseworkproject;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class activityresultsscreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activityresultsscreen);
}
final Button clickMe = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

public void buttonOnClick(View v) {
    clickMe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(activityresultsscreenActivity.this, SearchScreenActivity.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
        });}}
```

### activity_search_screen.xml

```
<TextView android:text="@string/titleApp" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
    android:textSize="20dp" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/search"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="119dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:background="#e0e0e0"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:onClick="switchactivityforward" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:background="#dadada" />
```

### activityresultscreen.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffffff">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="63dp"
    android:background="#1948e4"
    android:headerDividersEnabled="false" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="@string/titleRes"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_orange_light" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/goback"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:background="#bab8b8"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="12dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:onClick="@string/switchactivityback" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

### Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="uk.ac.city.acnh478.courseworkproject" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity android:name=".SearchScreenActivity" ></activity>
    <activity android:name=".activityresultsscreenActivity" android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

</application>
```

logcat:

```
11-03 21:55:31.490 2043-2043/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
11-03 21:55:31.490 2043-2043/? I/art: Late-enabling JIT
11-03 21:55:31.490 2043-2043/? I/art: JIT created with      code_cache_capacity=2MB compile_threshold=1000
 11-03 21:55:32.340 2043-2043/? W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/uk.ac.city.acnh478.courseworkproject-2/lib/x86_64
11-03 21:55:33.060 2043-2043/uk.ac.city.acnh478.courseworkproject D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
11-03 21:55:33.060 2043-2043/uk.ac.city.acnh478.courseworkproject E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 11-03 21:55:33.060 2043-2043/uk.ac.city.acnh478.courseworkproject         E/AndroidRuntime: Process: uk.ac.city.acnh478.courseworkproject, PID: 2043
  11-03 21:55:33.060 2043-2043/uk.ac.city.acnh478.courseworkproject  E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity  ComponentInfo{uk.ac.city.acnh478.courseworkproject/uk.ac.city.acnh478.courseworkproject.activityresultsscreenActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.Window.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
   11-03 21:55:33.060 2043-2043/uk.ac.city.acnh478.courseworkproject E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2327)
   11-03 21:55:33.060 2043-2043/uk.ac.city.acnh478.courseworkproject E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
   11-03 21:55:33.060 2043-2043/uk.ac.city.acnh478.courseworkproject   E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
   11-03 21:55:33.060 2043-2043/uk.ac.city.acnh478.courseworkproject E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
   11-03 21:55:33.060 2043-2043/uk.ac.city.acnh478.courseworkproject E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    11-03 21:55:33.060 2043-2043/uk.ac.city.acnh478.courseworkproject E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    11-03 21:55:33.060 2043-2043/uk.ac.city.acnh478.courseworkproject E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    11-03 21:55:33.060 2043-2043/uk.ac.city.acnh478.courseworkproject E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    11-03 21:55:33.060 2043-2043/uk.ac.city.acnh478.courseworkproject E/AndroidRuntime:     at  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    11-03 21:55:33.060 2043-2043/uk.ac.city.acnh478.courseworkproject E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
   11-03 21:55:33.060 2043-2043/uk.ac.city.acnh478.courseworkproject E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.Window.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
  11-03 21:55:33.060 2043-2043/uk.ac.city.acnh478.courseworkproject E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:2090)
   11-03 21:55:33.060 2043-2043/uk.ac.city.acnh478.courseworkproject  E/AndroidRuntime:     at uk.ac.city.acnh478.courseworkproject.activityresultsscreenActivity.<init>(activityresultsscreenActivity.java:16)
    11-03 21:55:33.060 2043-2043/uk.ac.city.acnh478.courseworkproject E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
     11-03 21:55:33.060 2043-2043/uk.ac.city.acnh478.courseworkproject E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1067)
     11-03 21:55:33.060 2043-2043/uk.ac.city.acnh478.courseworkproject E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2317)
     11-03 21:55:33.060 2043-2043/uk.ac.city.acnh478.courseworkproject E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
     11-03 21:55:33.060 2043-2043/uk.ac.city.acnh478.courseworkproject E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
      11-03 21:55:33.060 2043-2043/uk.ac.city.acnh478.courseworkproject E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
     11-03 21:55:33.060 2043-2043/uk.ac.city.acnh478.courseworkproject E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
  11-03 21:55:33.060 2043-2043/uk.ac.city.acnh478.courseworkproject E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
   11-03 21:55:33.060 2043-2043/uk.ac.city.acnh478.courseworkproject E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
 11-03 21:55:33.060 2043-2043/uk.ac.city.acnh478.courseworkproject E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
  11-03 21:55:33.060 2043-2043/uk.ac.city.acnh478.courseworkproject E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
   11-03 21:55:33.060 2043-2043/uk.ac.city.acnh478.courseworkproject E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: can you show your error log?

Comment: Add your logcat output so we can see where it may be dropping.

Comment: added the logcat to the original

Answer (score 0):

So there are a few issues with your code that I can see. 
When using the onClick method you need your code to implement OnClickListener otherwise your code won't execute fully. By implementing an OnClickLisenter your activity acts both as an Activity as well as an OnClickListener. This is especially useful when you have multiple buttons executing different activities.

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class SearchScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_screen);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.button;
            startActivity(new Intent(SearchScreenActivity.this,activityresultsscreenActivity.class));
            break;
    }
  }
}
```

And you would do something very similar in your other class as well. Now being that you only have one button another option would be done by using an Anonymous Inner class which is just as easy.

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class SearchScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button clickMe2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_screen);
    clickMe2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    clickMe2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(SearchScreenActivity.this,activityresultsscreenActivity.class));
        }
    });
  }
}
```